Which agent is best for cleaning epoxyfloor from carbon black powder?
I have a question regarding carbon black powder. Which detergent/agent is best for removing carbon black powder from epoxy floors? large amounts of Carbon Black powder has leaked after production, all over the epoxy floor. What can get this off the floor?

For a part of carbon, that is on surface and is not bound to it strongly, any usual detergent for floor cleaning would work.
But a part of carbon dust can be mechanically bonded to crevices in the floor surface. None of detergents will remove it.
More aggressive methods, attacking the epoxyfloor, like organic solvents, could cause much more harm than assumed gain.
If esthetic criteria are significant, it is possible that the only reasonable way is abrasive treatment of the floor and then applying a new layer, if at all applicable.
